# C# WPF XAML: Layout issues with dynamic stretching, statusbar and horizontal datagrid expansion

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I split my **WinMain.xaml** into 3 sections (menu, frame (for page) and a statusbar):

```
<Window x:Class="myCrazyApp.WinMain"
    ...
    MinHeight="600" MinWidth="1000">

    <DockPanel  Width="{Binding ActualWidth,  RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}"
               Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource = {RelativeSource AncestorType = {x:Type Window}}}">

        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="20">
            ...MenuItems...
        </Menu>

        <Frame DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="WinMain_FrameContent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Source="Pages\PageOne.xaml" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>

        <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="LightSlateGray" Height="32">
            <StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="60"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    </Grid>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </StatusBar.ItemsPanel>
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="0">
                <TextBlock Name="WinMain_TB_Log" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="1" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="2">
                <ProgressBar Name="WinMain_PB" Value="0" Width="170" Height="16" />
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="3" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="4">
                <Label Content="Status:"/>
            </StatusBarItem>
            <Separator Grid.Column="5" />
            <StatusBarItem Grid.Column="6" Padding="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Name="WinMain_TB_Status" />
            </StatusBarItem>
        </StatusBar>
    </DockPanel>
```

Then I have my **PageOne.xaml** filled with a datagrid:

```
<Page x:Class="myCrazyApp.PageOne"
  ...>

<DockPanel Background="Beige">
    <Label DockPanel.Dock="Top">MyTitle</Label>

    <Grid DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <DataGrid x:Name="myDataGrid" x:FieldModifier="public" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="500" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" EnableRowVirtualization="True" Margin="0,0,0,171" />
    </Grid>
</DockPanel>
```

1) The status bar in the main window is not at the bottom but instead below the middle of the window and overlapped by the pages content. Why?

2) The page adapts its size horizontally to the size of the main window (which is correct) but does not vertically adapt. Why?

3) The data grid in the page does not show a vertical scrollbar and does not end horizontally at its last column (instead: it stretches endlessly to the right with an empty column/grid). Why?

Sorry for asking 3-4 questions at once but I am bogused, here.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1)

Because you have set the `DockPanel.Dock` attached property to `Top` for both the `Menu` and the `Frame` and the last child fills the `DockPanel` unless you set `LastChildFill` to `false`. Besides, the `DockPanel` fills it parent container by default so it makes no sense to bind to the `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` properties of the window.

Remove `DockPanel.Dock="Top"` from the `Frame` and move it below the `StatusBar`. Then the `Frame` will fill the middle "row" of the `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel>

    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="20">
        ...
    </Menu>

    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="LightSlateGray" Height="32">
        ...
    </StatusBar>

    <Frame>...</Frame>

</DockPanel>
```

> 2)

It should be fixed by doing the above and possiblly also decrease the bottom margin of the `DataGrid` in the `Page`:

```
Margin="0,0,0,171"
```

> 3)

Because the `Frame` doesn't fill the `DockPanel` as expected. See 1).

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mm8! This solved all issues.

By the way, the `margin 171` was not on purpose but I guess, I inserted it accidently by clicking on the wrong object within the XAML editor.